A telegram bot that sends a message at a certain time, while continuing to work
How to write a bot that will perform a function once every time, while continuing to perform other tasks. I tried it through multithreading, it complains that several copies of the bot are being created. Due to asynchrony it does not want to work correctly.
import telegram
import schedule
import time

# Указываем id бота и токен
bot = telegram.Bot(token='YOUR_TOKEN')
chat_id = 'YOUR_CHAT_ID'

# Функция, которая будет отправлять сообщение
def send_message():
    message = 'Сообщение, которое нужно отправить в 21:00'
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

# Задаем время отправки сообщения
schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(send_message)

# Бесконечный цикл для проверки расписания
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

This option is not suitable because when it is executed in the While loop, everything else will not be executed.
import asyncio
import json
import logging
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
BOT_TOKEN = 'key'
CHANNELS_FILE = "channels.json"
bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
MESSAGE_TEXT = "Бот был добавлен в канал с ID: "

try:
    with open(CHANNELS_FILE, 'r') as f:
        channel_ids = set(json.load(f))
except FileNotFoundError:
    channel_ids = set()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(
        "Привет! Я бот, который будет выводить ID канала, куда его добавили, в консоль.\nПросто добавьте меня в "
        "канал, и я выведу его ID.")


@dp.channel_post_handler()
async def channel_post(message: types.Message):
    channel_id = message.chat.id
    if channel_id not in channel_ids:
        channel_ids.add(channel_id)
        with open(CHANNELS_FILE, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(list(channel_ids), f)
        print(f"Бот был добавлен в канал с ID: {channel_id}")


async def send_message_to_channels():
    for channel_id in channel_ids:
        await bot.send_message(channel_id, MESSAGE_TEXT)


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling()
    scheduler.add_job(send_message_to_channels, 'interval', seconds=10)
    await scheduler.start()
    await dp.wait_closed()


if name == 'main':
    asyncio.run(main())


Could you please translate the first part of the post in English?

Ready. Translated

python-telegram-bot/examples/timerbot.py it seems telegram has job queue to execute task with delay.

scheduled tasks - Telegram bot to send auto message every n hours with python-telegram-bot - Stack Overflow
